# method clear() in ArrayDeque

Tags: java, collections, arraydeque

Why in `ArrayDeque` for clear this one, using (1)do-while for removing every element instead create new array with start size and (2)overwrite array where contains elements?

(1)

```
public void clear() {
    int h = head;
    int t = tail;
    if (h != t) { // clear all cells
        head = tail = 0;
        int i = h;
        int mask = elements.length - 1;
        do {
            elements[i] = null;
            i = (i + 1) & mask;
        } while (i != t);
    }
}
```

(2)

```
public void clear() {
     head = tail = 0;
     elements = null;
     elements = (T[]) Object[START_SIZE]; 
}
```

Comment: Are you asking why the JDK uses (1) instead of (2)?

Comment: Your second option shrinks `elements` to initial size instead of preserving current size of array

Comment: It's also generally worth pointing out that whenever you create an array, [all of its elements are required to be initialized to a default value](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.2). This means that when you do `new Object[n]`, the JVM may immediately set all of the *n* elements to `null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you would want to explicitly set each element to `null` in `clear()` is that otherwise you could introduce a form of memory leak. That is, the `elements[]` array could hold onto references to objects and prevent them from being garbage collected.

Your alternative of recreating the array from scratch would work (I think you're missing a `new` though), but allocating a new chunk of memory is generally slower than clearing one you've already been allocated.

Comment: @ELEVATE I have two question:
 1. Where method clear() can use in practice?

Comment: @ELEVATE 2. For example, if i have ArrayDeque with 1000 elements, and I need empty ArrayDeque, what approach will be better?

Comment: @ELEVATE And one more:
3. If I rewrite as in approach 2, will older array be destroyed by garbage collector?

Comment: Yes, if the entire array is replaced the old one will be available for garbage collection. I would always null the elements as that doesn't require any memory allocation. Allocating a new buffer also fills that buffer with nulls, behind the scenes, so probably won't be any faster.